# JavaScript function definition in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

There are many JavaScript include files in my page. I need to find the location of the JavaScript function named "addIndustryBtnClick(this)". I did the following steps:

1. Opened Dev Tool in **Chrome**
2. Selected "Sources" on top.
3. Selected "Sources" from left window.
4. Clicked on the directory name of the project.

Now I can see the page source on the middle window.

I have searched the function name and it is highlighted with yellow color.

*Here is the screen shot of the current window:*
[image]

I have searched on each JavaScript include files on the left window and I could find the function definition. But is it possible to find function definition without going to each JavaScript file?

Comment: "that doesn't work for me" in what way doesn't it work? You can't find the global search screen? Or the search returns nothing? There's multiple ways to define a function, which is why search might not find it.

Comment: Hmm. someone just posted the identical question less than 24 hours ago. Did you search StackOverflow yet?

Comment: Did my answer below work out for you?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes made to your question.

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar I have included the steps which I did and the issue which I am facing now into the main post.

Comment: @Web_Developer You simply need to drag up the window on the very bottom of the screen. http://i.imgur.com/PRomW2S.png

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar Yes, you are correct. The window was hidden and I could only understand that, when an answer posted from a user with image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to search through a series of files for a specific
  JavaScript function without manually digging through each file, you
  can do that by selecting the tab on the lower console and running
  your search there.

[image]

Comment: @Web_Developer Dude, your question keeps changing.

Comment: @Web_Developer Updated my answer to reflect your changes.